# PostgreSQL unique indexes and string case

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

If I create a PostgreSQL unique index on a field, is the comparison case-insensitive by default?

If not, is it possible to ask PostgreSQL to ignore string case?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

PostgreSQL is case sensitive.  To do what you want create a function index. So say

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_upper_idx ON mytable (UPPER(myfield));
```

That way when you use `UPPER(myfield)` in your query the index will be used.

[See this link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/indexes-expressional.html)

Comment: @szeryf Better in what way? Anything to prove that it's better?

Comment: These solutions do not get triggered when we have an `INSERT.... ON CONFLICT (myfield)...`

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_table_field ON mytable(UPPER(field))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be to make you column data type a `citext` (case-insensitive text).

> The `citext` module provides a case-insensitive character string type, `citext`. Essentially, it internally calls `lower` when comparing values. Otherwise, it behaves almost exactly like `text`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    nick CITEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    pass TEXT   NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 'larry',  sha256(random()::text::bytea) );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 'Tom',    sha256(random()::text::bytea) );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 'Damian', sha256(random()::text::bytea) );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 'NEAL',   sha256(random()::text::bytea) );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 'Bjørn',  sha256(random()::text::bytea) );

SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick = 'Larry';
```

This way tou do not need to calll the `lower` function on the index creation.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_users_on_nick ON users (nick);
```

Usefull links:

- [PostgreSQL citext](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/citext.html)
- [shuber Case insensitive UNIQUE constraints in Postgres](http://shuber.io/case-insensitive-unique-constraints-in-postgres/)

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to create a function based index. (use the `UPPER` of the field)