# Is it possible to force values of a column to be lowercase

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, case-insensitive

I'm working with PostgreSQL 9.3.

I have a table with a `varchar` column that I always want to be filled with lowercase strings.

I could use the Postgres `lower` function before saving my values, but is there instead a way to define this column as a lowercase column?

Comment: You could define the field as case-insensitive text (CITEXT) which isn't what you asked for but might give you what you want.

Comment: If I do so, add a unique constraint and try to save 'AaaA' then 'aaaa', will I get a unique exception?

Comment: Yes you will if you create the field as UNIQUE e.g. `create table t (f citext unique);`

Comment: Ok thanks, it fits my needs.

Comment: You can create a trigger that converts any input to lowercase

Comment: Do you think that it is a better way to do what I need? (instead of create a "citext" field)

Comment: [`citext`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/citext.html) is probably better than any hand-knit solution - if the [limitations](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/citext.html#AEN155284) are not a problem for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005302/postgresql-how-to-make-not-case-sensitive-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a simple check in the column:

```
create table lower_field (
    field1 varchar check (field1 = lower(field1))
    );
```