# Rails custom model setter and querying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose there is a Rails model with a [custom setter/accessor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord%3a%3aBase-label-Overwriting+default+accessors) and a uniqueness constraint on the `name` column:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  def name=(name)
    # Example transformation only. 
    # Could be substituted for a more complex operation/transformation.
    title_cased = name.titleize 
    self[:name] = title_cased
  end

end
```

Now, consider the following:

```
Person.create! name: "John Citizen"
Person.find_or_create_by! name: "john citizen" # Error: validation fails
```

The `find` operation will not find any results, since there are no entries that match "john citizen". Then, the `create!` operation will throw an error as there is already an existing entry "John Citizen" (`create!` creates a new record and raises an exception if the validation fails).

How do you *elegantly* prevent such errors from occurring? For loose coupling and encapsulation purposes, is it possible to *not* transform names (to titlecase, in this case) before I perform operations like `find_or_create_by!` or other operations like `find_by`?

EDIT:
As @harimohanraj alludes to, the issue seems to be around equivalence. Should the model transparently deal with the understanding/translating input to its boiled-down, canonical state. Or should this be the responsibility of consumers of the class/model?

Also, is [active record callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) a recommended approach to this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined a custom setter method, the implicit decision that you have made is: values for the `name` attribute, no matter what form they come in (eg. a user's input in a text field), should be handled in titleized form in your DB. If that's the case, then it makes sense that `find_or_create_by! name: 'john citizen'` fails! In other words, your custom setter method represents your decision that "John Citizen" and "john citizen" are one and the same.

If you find yourself wanting to store `John Citizen` *and* `john citizen` in your DB, then I would revisit your decision to create a custom setter method. One cool way to achieve "loose coupling" is to put all of the logic that sanitizes data (ex. data from a user filling out a form) into a separate Ruby object.

There isn't much context in the question, so here is a bit of an abstract example to demonstrate what I mean.

```
# A class to house the logic of sanitizing your parameters
class PersonParamsSanitizer
  # It is initialized with dirty user parameters
  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  # It spits out neat, titleized params
  def sanitized_params
    {
      name: @params[:name].titleize
    }
  end
end

class PersonController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Use your sanitizer object to convert dirty user parameters into neat
    # titleized params for your new perons
    sanitized_params = UserParamsSanitizer.new(params).sanitized_params

    person = Person.new(sanitized_params)

    if person.save
      redirect_to person
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

This way, you don't override the setter method in your User model, and are free to use `find_or_create_by!` fearlessly if you so choose!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `find_or_create_by` and similar methods are already *not* tansforming the name... as you say there is no record "john citizen" but to work properly you'd need to titleize it for the `find_or_create_by`, `find_or_create_by!`, or `find_by`

(you don't need this solution for `find` as that only retrieves record by primary key)

so...

```
def self.find_or_create_by(options)
  super(rectify_options(options))
end

def self.find_or_create_by!(options)
  super(rectify_options(options))
end

def self.find_by(options)
  super(rectify_options(options))
end

private

def self.rectify_options(options)
  options[:name] = (new.name = options[:name]) if options[:name]
  options
end
```

Comment: Thank you :) I guess this would solve the problem for `find_or_create_by`, but what about other other operations likes `find` or `find_or_create_by!` etc? I wasn't very clear in my question about this (sorry!)

Comment: Hi, ok, question edited to extend for find_or_create_by! and `find_by`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a validation to be case-insensitive by using:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, 
            presence: true, 
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

However you also need a case-insensitive database index backing it since [just using a validation in Rails will lead to race conditions](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations). How to achieve that depends on the RBDMS.

Which leaves the issue of querying. The classic way of performing a intensive search is by `WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER(?)`. Although Postgres lets you use `WHERE ILIKE name = ?`.

If you want to encapsulate this into the model which is a good idea you would create a scope:

```
class Person
  scope :find_by_name, lambda{ |name| where('LOWER(name) = LOWER(?)', name) }
end
```

However, you cannot use `.find_or_create_by!` in this case as the query not just a hash. Instead you would call `.first_or_create`.

```
Person.find_by_name("John Citizen").first_or_create(attrs)
```

### see also

- [PostgreSQL: How to make "case-insensitive" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005302/postgresql-how-to-make-not-case-sensitive-queries)

Comment: You could override the ActiveRecord finder methods to use case-insentive queries but its going to be a hacky mess. Instead I would document that the  case insentive query method should be used.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't very clear. My example is contrived, and is not a specific to title casing. Instead of `titleize`, it could be a more complex operation and the output could be significantly different to the input. I've updated my question now.