# How to search a postgres JSONb column with wildcards in ruby activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

I have a postgres table (Users) that has a JSONb column (metadata). At the moment I am searching for a User by email and it works just fine except that the email must be an exact match.

So if a user has email `bob@smith.com` and I do `User.by_email("bob@smith.com")` it works grand. But I would like `User.by_email("@smith.com")` to return all users with an email that matches.

In my `user.rb` model I have the following:

```
scope :by_email, ->(email) { where("metadata @> ?", { session: { Primary: { Email: email.to_s.downcase} } }.to_json) }
```

Which is what allows `User.by_email(email)` to work. How can I modify that to find all users that have an email matching the string passed in?

The second part to this is that I would like to be able to search by User's name as well.

This would be done via `scope :by_name, ->(name) { where("metadata @> ?", { session: { Primary: { FullName: name.to_s} } }.to_json) }`

How can I do these both at the same time? If this was just simple activerecord I know I could do:

```
User.where("full_name LIKE ? OR email LIKE", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
```

How can I do this with a JSONb column?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
User.where("metadata->'session'->'Primary'->>'Email' LIKE ?", '%@smith.com')
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
Note that you might want `ILIKE` for case insensitive searching https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005302/postgresql-how-to-make-case-insensitive-query/19475095#19475095