# Knex Query with Like + '%' is not working

Tags: node.js, knex.js, adonis.js

I have this query that have to select all books filtering by a description ignoring uppercase/lowercase.

So I make this query in adonis.js / node.js:

```
 const queryBook = Book
            .query()
            .with('user')
 queryBook.where('description', 'like', '%'+bookDescription[0]+'%')
```

I have records with this `bookDescription`:

**"Espanhol for Students ed.1   "**

But when I try to filter using only "es" in lowercase, the knex don't return any record.

When I put "Es", return the book with the description that I put, so, the like %es% is not working.

I put one debug and I catch this:

```
knex:query select * from "books" where "description" like ? limit ? undefined +7ms
knex:bindings [ '%es%', 10 ] undefined +6ms
```

Apparently I don't find any wrong, but I think the `like` must return the record in lowercase..

I'm forgetting something?

Comment: which DB are you using? Postgres or mysql?

Comment: @Pavan i'm using postgres

Comment: Use `ilike` for postgres case insesntive matching

Comment: i also tried with ilike: queryBook.where('description', 'ilike', bookDescription[0]) but i'm still receiving no records

Comment: can you run the query in your SQL client and see if it returns the results?

Comment: @Jhonny Have you read this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005302/postgresql-how-to-make-case-insensitive-query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use like this

```
const queryBook = Book
            .query()
            .with('user')
 queryBook.where('description', 'like', `%${bookDescription[0]}%`)
```

or

```
const queryBook = Book
            .query()
            .with('user')
 queryBook.where('description', 'ilike', `%${bookDescription[0]}%`)
```

More Info. view [knexjs](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereNotIn) docuemnts

Answer (score 4):

For case insensitive search you can use following like query

```
const queryBook = Book
        .query()
        .with('user')
queryBook.whereRaw(`LOWER(description) LIKE ?`, [`%${bookDescription[0]}%`])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using latest knexjs (> 1.x.x)
one can use whereIlike or orWhereILike

```
const result = await select('*').from('books').whereILike('description',`${'%'+searchterm+'%'}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this best way

```js
knex.whereILike('name',`%${search.toLowerCase()}%`);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please, always explain your answer.