# PostgreSQL in clause with ignore case values

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jpql, postgresql-9.5

I'm taking this link - [PostgreSQL: How to make "case-insensitive" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005302/postgresql-how-to-make-case-insensitive-query) and asking a question.

I am looking to pass values and should get response for case insensitive as well.

> select * from account_role where descr in ('Acquirer','Advisors');

If I pass values like `acquirer` and `advisors` it should work. If I pass values like '`ACQUIRER`' and '`ADVISORS`'.

The same query I've to use in JPQL where I've join with other tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your values as an `ARRAY` and use `ANY` in combination with `ILIKE` to make it case insensitive, e.g.

```
WITH j (txt) AS (
  VALUES ('ACQUIRER'),('ADVISORS')
) 
SELECT * FROM j 
WHERE txt ILIKE ANY (ARRAY['AcQuIrEr', 'AdvisorS']);

   txt    
----------
 ACQUIRER
 ADVISORS
```

See this [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4c68925df2fb7f9ac2f4769aca9a00c5)