# Django case insensitive in check against list

Tags: django, python-3.x, orm

My site has a bunch of Thread objects

```
  >>> Thread.objects.filter(board__name='Fitness')
    [<Thread: lorem>, <Thread: lorems>, <Thread: LOREM>]
```

And each user has a list of filters, (Postgresql Array Field)

```
>>> filters
['lorem', 'adipisci', 'amet', 'dolor']
```

I want be to able to exclude threads that are in the users filter list. So far this is the only way I've been able to achieve this:

```
>>> Thread.objects.filter(board__name='Fitness').exclude(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(title__icontains=x) for x in filters)))
[]
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to do case insensitive checks in Django with the in operator. Since the below does not work

```
>>> Thread.objects.filter(board__name='Fitness').exclude(title__in=filters)
[<Thread: lorems>, <Thread: LOREM>]
```

Preferably from within Django, and not having to mess with the Database itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django query case-insensitive list match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667524/django-query-case-insensitive-list-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [iregex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#iregex), in the following way:

```
>>> Thread.objects.filter(board__name="Fitness") \
                  .exclude(title__iregex=r"(" + "|".join(filters) + ")$")
[<Thread: lorems>]
```