# Django - correct way to convert list to combined OR for Q object

Tags: python, django

I have QueryDict with list `'value': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']` - number of elements is unknown. I need convert this list to filter model using OR condition:

```
 Poll.objects.get(Q(value__icontains=option[0]) | Q(value__icontains=option[1]))
```

In SQL:

```
AND (value LIKE '%1%' OR value LIKE '%2%')
```

How to achieve this correct and easy way ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `reduce` operation to combine the Q objects.

**Solution**:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
options = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

# uses operator or to combine the Q objects with the particular option filter
query = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(value__icontains=option) for option in options))

polls = Poll.objects.get(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Poll.objects.get(value__in=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])` should do it.

Or, for case insensitive query, see here: [Django query case-insensitive list match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667524/django-query-case-insensitive-list-match)

Comment: That is not the same as an `icontains` query that the OP is looking for.

Comment: You're correct; updated answer.

Comment: @TeaPow Still not the same. In your query the value has to be one of the strings in the list, the OP needs value only to contain one of them.

Comment: @SachinKukreja Nah, it is OR. One hit from the list will do.