# Django queryset where a field values are in a list

Tags: python, regex, django, django-queryset

I need to make a query that returns all rows where the field **subject** values exist in a list. I don't matter with sensitive case, but the values should be exact with the ones in the list.

I'm using:

```
my_list = ["Others", "Entertainment"]
results = MyObject.objects.filter(subject__iregex=r"(" + "|".join(my_list) + ")")
```

This is the solution from the topic [Django query case-insensitive list match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667524/django-query-case-insensitive-list-match) but as result I have rows where:

```
subject = "others tv series"
```

and I just want rows like:

```
subject = "others"
```

I need something like **iexact** and **in** mixed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the start and end of line specifies in Regex, `^` and `$`, respectively:

```
subject__iregex=r"^(" + "|".join(my_list) + ")$"
```

I find `str.format` to be more readable (for Python 3.6+ also look at f-strings):

```
'^({})$'.format('|'.join(my_list))
```

As we are not referring to the captured group later-on, we can make the group non-capturing:

```
'^(?:{})$'.format('|'.join(my_list))
```

Comment: @PaulozOiOzuLLuFabrício It builds the Regex correctly. Check out for any whitespaces around the `subject` field's value. Also you are using `__iregex`, right?

Comment: Yeah! It's ok! In the question I used the field subject, but in my code I need the field category, LOL. I changed my code and it works like a charm! Thanks, man!

Comment: @PaulozOiOzuLLuFabrício it happens! Glad I could help :)