# How to use case insensitive in operation in django orm?

Tags: django, orm, lookup

```
User.objects.filter(name__in=["A", "AB", "a", "ab", "Ab"])
```

This is an example of using `in` field lookup in `Django`.

But I want to know that is here any trick of using `in` as case insensitive  like `icontains` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Others' answers are excellent.

I looked for another way that use [Lower function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#lower)

```
lower_list = map(lambda x:x.lower(), ["A", "AB", "a", "ab", "Ab"])
User.objects.annotate(name_lower=Lower('name').filter(name_lower__in=lower_list)
```

It's just another way. I think that other people's answers are close to a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

For case insensitive operation you can use `iregex`

```
User.objects.filter(name__iregex=r'(A|AB|a|ab|Ab)')
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iregex

**Update:**
You can make own lookup. Get help from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/lookups/

Answer (score 1):

According to [Django query case-insensitive list match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667524/django-query-case-insensitive-list-match) there is no solution other then do `iregex` lookup